# Upload file then forward it

Tags: php, post, cross-domain

I want to upload a file from one domain to another then forward that upload.

For example: a user uploads a jpg file from `domain1.com` to `domain2.com`. Then `domain2.com` forwards the file to `domain3.com`. I also need the GET content to forward on as well.

I have tried this on domain 2:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^POST
RewriteRule ^uploader.php https://domain3.com/upload.php  [L]
```

Basically, I set it up so `domain1.com` has a form that uploads the file to `domain2.com/uploader.php`. Then `domain2.com` redirects the user to `domain3.com/upload.php` with the post data.

All 3 domains are on different servers.

How do I forward POST and GET data?

Comment: What purpose does `domain2` serve? If you want the data on `domain3` why not redirect straight there?

Comment: It is for API. Domain2 needs some of the file's information.